# Why exactly templates are needed in CQ?

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, aem, wcm

Why exactly do we need templates when all a template does is to have a `resourceType` property attached to a content-page component.

At the time of creating new page, shouldn't authors directly select that component instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template nodes define the metadata for the page that will be created, *one* aspect of which is the underlying resource type (i.e. the Page component that will be used to render out the content).

Some example of other things configured at a template level include:

1. The **default content** that is included when the page is created. This
   is stored under the template node itself, i.e. in `/apps/[your-site]/templates/homepage`.

   For example, you could add a `carousel`node underneath the homepage node, to ensure that any page created with the homepage template will have a carousel node added by default.
2. The **allowed parents & children of the template** — e.g. configuring the homepage template so that it can't be placed beneath other templates.
3. The **allowed components in each parsys** — In `/etc/designs/[your-design]/jcr:content`, you can defined what components can be added to a particular parsys, which applies to any page using that template.

By having a separation between templates & page components it allows us to re-use the same renderers (e.g. JSP scripts), but have aspects like these configured differently for different templates.